# python plot points

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

Using pylab I am plotting a set of points like this:

```
plt.plt(row[1], row[2]);
```

Which correctly plots a line between these points, however as well as this line, I want to plot the actual points. So the points and the line, to get the points:

```
plt.plt(row[1], row[2], "bo");
```

How can I combine both of these in the plot? Is there a simple way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe pylab relies on matplotlib.  If this is the case, then something like this should work.

```
plt.plt(row[1], row[2], 'b-', marker='o');
```

See the section about *kwargs* [in the documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).